# exporting 3d polygon mesh in obj file

Tags: 3d, polygon, meshlab

I am working on a 3d project, and to do that I use meshLab, the problem is I cant get meshLab to export the mesh in obj format, when I try it the program just freeze or crash. I tried on a small cube and it worked but then when I tried on a model which is about 6 mb it crashed (the models I am working on are 25 - 500 mb).

Any help will be amazing, thx

Answer (score 0):

I usually have no problem exporting big files (5 Million vertex, 330M in .ply format) to obj

If you can save your file to .ply format, maybe you can try to convert to .obj externally using :
`meshlabserver -i file.ply -o file.obj`